# Web editor control throwing error on <br> when I make new line

Tags: c#, asp.net

Read this error -> webeditor error on break point

> A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderMain_WebEditor1="gdfgvdfdfv

Answer (score 0):

if user enter non-encoded HTML content in webeditor control it gives this error...

so to prevent this, add `ValidateRequest="false"` to the "page" directive of that aspx file

Comment: i have added this but still have same  problem

Comment: in web.config, under <system.web>, do validations to false globally, <pages validateRequest="false" />

Comment: Exception Details: System.Web.HttpRequestValidationException: A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderMain_WebEditor1="gdfgvdfdfv<table><tbody><tr><t...").